# How to inject helm template scripts in the result of a renedered helm template?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to integrate helm with Hashicorp Vault.
There is a lot of context and in summary, I am following [this](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples) example with some modifications of myself.

But my question is not about vault integration. It is helm templating that I am stuck with.

**first question:**

I have this deployment.yaml file:

```
# deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: amin
  labels:
    app: amin
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: amin
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-0: internal/data/database/config
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-0: |
          {{- with secret "internal/data/database/config" -}}
             export user_name_amin="{{ .Data.data.username }}"
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: internal-app
      labels:
        app: amin
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: internal-app
      containers:
        - name: amin
          image: jweissig/app:0.0.1
```

If I run `kubectl -f deployment.yaml` it successfuly create a deployment named amin and If I do `kubectl exec deployment/amin -- cat /vault/secrets/0` it returns `export user_name_amin="db-readonly-username"` meaning that it works as expected.

now if I do the same using the helm install command it wont work.

The helm install command should replace all the templates but should treat this part as text

```
          {{- with secret "internal/data/database/config" -}}
             export user_name_amin="{{ .Data.data.username }}"
          {{- end }}
```

How can I do this so that during the helm install command this part gets ignored?

**One level harder**

suppose I wanted to replace part of the content of

```
          {{- with secret "internal/data/database/config" -}}
             export user_name_amin="{{ .Data.data.username }}"
          {{- end }}
```

from the values.yaml file. suppose I had a values.yaml file in which I have stored `user_name_amin` in a variable? How could I render it and still render it as template inside the result of the helm render?

Comment: how is this question related to `go`?

Comment: A great deal of kubernetes is based on go. That does not mean kubernetes questions are in general on-topic. All questions must be specifically related to programming.

Comment: I think I found something helpful https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/issues/187

Comment: You need to escape the `{{` if you want it to appear in the final output.  I tend to write `{{ "{{" }}`.  The linked question has a more complete description, including this exact Vault-related setup.